# How can I debug why a specific kernel crashes when waking from suspend?

Tags: linux-mint, kernel, suspend

I am running Linux Mint 17 with the 3.x series kernel. Today I remembered that a recommended upgrade to the kernel had been sitting around for some weeks, so I thought it might be worth upgrading (in Mint, system updates are graded 1-5 depending on importance and stability, with 1 being most important or stable. These updates were a 5).

The upgrade moved my system from kernel 3.13.0-139-generic to linux-headers-3.13.0-149-generic. I have been having some minor and longstanding problems with VirtualBox interactions with the window manager, and I was vaguely hoping this would fix them. However, I soon noticed that the machine would not wake from sleep.

When I close the lid of my laptop, the machine goes to sleep seemingly successfully (the power light goes off, as long as the adaptor is not plugged in). With the new kernel, when opening the laptop, the display does not event come on, and the Caps Lock key does not affect the state of the LED on the key if pressed. In short, it looks like a very hard crash. I have to press-and-hold the power button to turn the system off, and then back on, in order to use the machine again.

I then tried using the old kernel (by holding down Esc at boot time and then choosing from the Grub menu) and this fixes it (temporarily, anyway, until the next system reboot).

I'd like to report this bug, or make sure it is reported. However, searching for "suspend wake-up Linux Mint 17" and similar variations does not seem specific enough, judging by the results I get. I'd like to be able to pin it down a bit more, by finding out what the issue is (e.g. see if there is a hardware driver error).

I imagine things like syslog and dmesg will help here, however I am not seeing much that looks like a culprit. Here is a section of my syslog that looks like it records the sleep/wake events:

```
May 25 21:24:44 jon-XPS13-9333 kernel: [  121.489960] Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
May 25 21:24:44 jon-XPS13-9333 kernel: [  121.490642] wlan0: deauthenticating from 28:be:03:xx:xx:xx by local choice (reason=3)
May 25 21:24:44 jon-XPS13-9333 kernel: [  121.507089] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
May 25 21:24:44 jon-XPS13-9333 kernel: [  121.507309] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
May 25 21:24:44 jon-XPS13-9333 kernel: [  121.509927] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Stopping disk
May 25 21:24:44 jon-XPS13-9333 kernel: [  123.203071] PM: suspend of devices complete after 1711.072 msecs
May 25 21:24:44 jon-XPS13-9333 kernel: [  123.219102] PM: late suspend of devices complete after 16.014 msecs
May 25 21:24:44 jon-XPS13-9333 kernel: [  123.235145] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
May 25 21:24:44 jon-XPS13-9333 kernel: [  123.267087] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
May 25 21:24:44 jon-XPS13-9333 kernel: [  123.283399] PM: noirq suspend of devices complete after 64.243 msecs
May 25 21:24:44 jon-XPS13-9333 kernel: [  123.283836] ACPI: Preparing to enter system sleep state S3
May 25 21:24:44 jon-XPS13-9333 kernel: [  123.284529] PM: Saving platform NVS memory
May 25 21:24:44 jon-XPS13-9333 kernel: [  123.285057] Disabling non-boot CPUs ...
May 25 21:24:44 jon-XPS13-9333 kernel: [  123.286339] kvm: disabling virtualization on CPU1
May 25 21:24:44 jon-XPS13-9333 kernel: [  123.387156] smpboot: CPU 1 is now offline
May 25 21:24:44 jon-XPS13-9333 kernel: [  123.387699] Broke affinity for irq 60
May 25 21:24:44 jon-XPS13-9333 kernel: [  123.388709] kvm: disabling virtualization on CPU2
May 25 21:24:44 jon-XPS13-9333 kernel: [  123.491238] smpboot: CPU 2 is now offline
May 25 21:24:44 jon-XPS13-9333 kernel: [  123.491752] Broke affinity for irq 23
May 25 21:24:44 jon-XPS13-9333 kernel: [  123.491754] Broke affinity for irq 56
May 25 21:24:44 jon-XPS13-9333 kernel: [  123.491755] Broke affinity for irq 57
May 25 21:24:44 jon-XPS13-9333 kernel: [  123.492762] kvm: disabling virtualization on CPU3
May 25 21:24:44 jon-XPS13-9333 kernel: [  123.595317] smpboot: CPU 3 is now offline
May 25 21:24:44 jon-XPS13-9333 kernel: [  123.597437] ACPI: Low-level resume complete
May 25 21:24:44 jon-XPS13-9333 kernel: [  123.597500] PM: Restoring platform NVS memory
May 25 21:24:44 jon-XPS13-9333 kernel: [  123.598008] Enabling non-boot CPUs ...
May 25 21:24:44 jon-XPS13-9333 kernel: [  123.598044] x86: Booting SMP configuration:
May 25 21:24:44 jon-XPS13-9333 kernel: [  123.598045] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 1 APIC 0x1
May 25 21:24:44 jon-XPS13-9333 kernel: [  123.610387] kvm: enabling virtualization on CPU1
May 25 21:24:44 jon-XPS13-9333 kernel: [  123.612817] CPU1 is up
May 25 21:24:44 jon-XPS13-9333 kernel: [  123.612836] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 2 APIC 0x2
May 25 21:24:44 jon-XPS13-9333 kernel: [  123.624985] kvm: enabling virtualization on CPU2
May 25 21:24:44 jon-XPS13-9333 kernel: [  123.627356] CPU2 is up
May 25 21:24:44 jon-XPS13-9333 kernel: [  123.627375] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 3 APIC 0x3
May 25 21:24:44 jon-XPS13-9333 kernel: [  123.639441] kvm: enabling virtualization on CPU3
May 25 21:24:44 jon-XPS13-9333 kernel: [  123.641803] CPU3 is up
May 25 21:24:44 jon-XPS13-9333 kernel: [  123.645965] ACPI: Waking up from system sleep state S3
May 25 21:24:44 jon-XPS13-9333 kernel: [  123.813893] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
May 25 21:24:44 jon-XPS13-9333 kernel: [  123.861939] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
May 25 21:24:44 jon-XPS13-9333 kernel: [  123.894081] PM: noirq resume of devices complete after 234.451 msecs
May 25 21:24:44 jon-XPS13-9333 kernel: [  123.894287] PM: early resume of devices complete after 0.185 msecs
May 25 21:24:44 jon-XPS13-9333 kernel: [  123.894375] usb usb2: root hub lost power or was reset
May 25 21:24:44 jon-XPS13-9333 kernel: [  123.894377] usb usb3: root hub lost power or was reset
May 25 21:24:44 jon-XPS13-9333 kernel: [  123.895481] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: irq 56 for MSI/MSI-X
May 25 21:24:44 jon-XPS13-9333 kernel: [  123.895533] mei_me 0000:00:16.0: irq 59 for MSI/MSI-X
May 25 21:24:44 jon-XPS13-9333 kernel: [  123.895639] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: irq 61 for MSI/MSI-X
May 25 21:24:44 jon-XPS13-9333 kernel: [  123.895764] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:03.0: irq 62 for MSI/MSI-X
May 25 21:24:44 jon-XPS13-9333 kernel: [  123.998226] dpm_run_callback(): pnp_bus_resume+0x0/0xa0 returns -19
May 25 21:24:44 jon-XPS13-9333 kernel: [  123.998227] PM: Device 00:06 failed to resume: error -19
May 25 21:24:44 jon-XPS13-9333 kernel: [  124.122152] usb 1-1: reset high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci-pci
```

The dmesg file also does not have things that look all that relevant - the unsuspend is visible, but no errors.

What other things can I investigate in order to be able to see if the bug has already been logged?

(Aside, I plan to upgrade to Linux Mint 18.x at some point, which will hopefully get rid of this issue, but in the short term I'll probably just downgrade my kernel to the old working one).